# Angular 9 new unit test error: "unsafe value used in a resource URL context"

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-dom-sanitizer

Since upgrading my Angular application from version 8 to version 9 I've got a new error appearing when I run my Jest unit test:

```
unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

The component I am testing uses the DomSanitizer:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() path: string;
  url: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( this.path );
  }

}
```

and this url is used on an iframe:

```
<iframe [src]="url" />
```

I am using Jest with Angular 9 and this occurs when taking a snapshot.

My Test (I've tried mocking it and not mocking it):

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ExampleComponent ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: DomSanitizer,
          useValue: {
            bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl: () => ''
          }
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should render', () => {
    expect(fixture).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no component lifecycle in tests. You have to invoke component cycle method yourself.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnInit();
  });
```

but since you have have an `@Input` which potentially can mutate, I would move logic from `ngOnInit` to `ngOnChanges` so your component can reflect dynamic binding changes - now it is only a one shot.

Comment: While your comment about lifecycle is correct, i still can't get rid of the error.

Comment: I needed to also remove my mock of the DomSanitizer.

Comment: Well that is obvious as you need to actually bypass security - since that is what error is all about.

Comment: what's the final working one - with Mock pipe, oninit and provider?

Answer (score 0):

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    sanitizerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('DomSanitizer', ['bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ExampleComponent ],
      providers: [
        DomSanitizer
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    sanitizerSpy.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl.and.callFake((value) => value as SafeResourceUrl);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Here is ex.